# How to erase text from .txt in python or AHK?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, automated-tests, autohotkey

I've a .txt file with 790 lines. In those lines theres information that I want to keep and information that I want to get rid off. Follow a example of what it looks like.

> ```
> InfoThatIWant:InfoThatIWant - InfoThatI**Don't**WantInfoThatI**Don't**WantInfoThatI**Don't**WantInfoThatI**Don't**Want BR1
> ```

> ```
> InfoThatIWant:InfoThatIWant - InfoThatI**Don't**WantInfoThatI**Don't**WantInfoThatI**Don't**WantInfoThatI**Don't**WantInfoThatI**Don't**WantInfoThatI**Don't**Want BR1
> ```

Thats how the documento go on till the end. So, as you guys can see, every line have the info I want till the "-" and the info I don't want starts at the "-" and ends in the BR1, everytime. That probably is the logic that I need to follow in order to automatic erase this lines.

I'm new to coding and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do that. Unfortunately I've no code example to index in here, but I'd aprecciate any information that u guys can give me.

Comment: readline and split every line by " - " , add your code please

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can go simply by reading each line independantly, then splitting your line with '-' and getting only the first element as following:

```
info_to_keep = []
with open('my_file.txt', 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        info_to_keep.append(line.split("-")[0])  # Getting your info

with open('my_file.txt', 'w+') as f:  # Overwritting the file with only the info you want
    for info in info_to_keep:
        f.write(info+"\n")
```

EDIT : Added how to re-write the file with only the info you want to keep

Comment: Man, you're an absolute legend. It worked like a charm. I just needed to add the enconding and was perfect. I really aprecciate ur help. As I'm very new I was struggling alot!

Comment: my pleasure, feel free to continue to use thise wonderful forum again !